# How to access dockerRegistryId when defining DockerSupportFeature in TeamCity Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

I have defined a TeamCity project with some templates and build configurations using the TeamCity Kotlin DSL.
The parent project of it is maintained in the GUI (i.e. is not defined in Kotlin DSL).
In the parent project I have defined a DockerRegistry connection which I want to use when defining the DockerSupport build feature in the build configuration. My code for defining this build feature looks like this:

```
object MyTemplate: {
  ...
  features {
    dockerSupport {
      loginToRegistry = on {
        dockerRegistryId = <here I want to access the id of the connection defined in the parent project>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I already tried to iterate through the project features when defining the project. But even though in the GUI it shows me the inherited connection, `features.items` of my subproject is empty.

Is there any way to access this id without hardcoding it?

Our TeamCity version is 2019.2

Comment: The 1st line is `object MyTemplate: Template {`, of course. How would I edit the question? I can't find a Button for that.